# Chart.js PolarArea Chart Labeling

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I searched throug the net, but couldn't find any helpful advice to solve my problem. I'm using chart.js and I want to create a polararea type chart. So far so good, but when I draw it there are no labels.

It looks like this:
[image]

But what I want is this:
[image]

EDIT Code:

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "polarArea",
    data: {
        labels: ["Vision", "Crossing", "Free Kick", "Short Passing", "Long Passing", "Curve"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "# of Votes",
            data: [99, 90, 99, 99, 89, 99],
            backgroundColor: [
                "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
            ],
            borderColor: [
                "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "rgba(25, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                "rgba(69, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                "rgba(25, 206, 86, 0.2)",
                "rgba(20, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                "rgba(13, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                "rgba(55, 159, 64, 0.2)"
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          scale: {
            display: false
          },title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Passing"
            },tooltips:{
                enabled:true,
            },
    },
});
```

Comment: could you share your code as well?

Comment: Edited the Code above ;)

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, you want to display "Vision", "Crossing", "Free Kick", "Short Passing", "Long Passing", "Curve" as legends ?

Comment: No, not as Legends. Legends can displayed when I set it to true. But they will show up in a row at the top. But I want to position them to their graph around the chart like in the picture: beneath the green graph there is the 25 --> for my code: beneath the vision graph there is the label "vision"